# Extracting Text from a PDF file with embedded font

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I have a PDF file containing some tabular data.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44235928/sample_rotate-0.pdf

I have to extract the tabular data from it. I have tried following with no success :

1. Select the text and paste it to notepad/excel-sheet. (I am getting junk characters)
2. Used save as text from Acrobat Reader. It is also giving junk characters and not the actual text.
3. Tried ApachePDFBox command line utility to extract text from PDF. It is also giving junk characters instead of real texts.
4. Finally I am trying a OCR solution. I am converting the pdf file into .tif images using ImageMagick  and getting those images processed by tesseract OCR.

The OCR solution is not very accurate though( about 80% words matched ).

I tried changing density and geometry of the image created from PDF to get better results from tesseract OCR.

```
convert -rotate 90 -geometry 10000 -depth 8 -density 800 sample.pdf img_800_10000.tif;
tesseract img_800_10000.tif img_800_10000.tif nobatch letters;
```

I am not sure for what kind of image( density, geometry, monochromatic, sharpen boundary etc) would be best suited for the OCR.

Please suggest what could be the best possible parameters(density,geometry,depth etc) for generating images from a PDF file, so that the tesseract accuracy will increase.

I am open to other( non-ocr ) solutions as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I recommend to **NOT** use ImageMagick for the PDF -> TIFF conversion. Instead, use Ghostscript. Two reasons:

1. Using Ghostscript directly will give you more control over individual parameters of the conversion.
2. ImageMagick cannot do that particular conversion itself -- it will call Ghostscript as its *'delegate'* anyway, but will not allow you to give all the same fine-grained control that your own Ghostscript command will give you.

Most of the text in the table of your sample PDF is extremely small (I guess, only 4 or 5 pt high). This makes it rather difficult to run a successful OCR unless you increase the resolution considerably.

Ghostscript uses `-r72` by default for image format output (such as TIFF). Tesseract works best with r=300 or r=400 -- but only for a font size from 10-12 pt or higher. Therefor, to compensate for the small text size you should make Ghostscript using a resolution of at least 1200 DPI when it renders the PDF to the image.

Also, you'll have to rotate the image so the text displays in the normal reading direction (not bottom -> top).

This is the command which I would try first:

```
gs                              \
  -o sample.tif                 \
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4               \
  -r1200                        \
  -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage \
   sample_rotate-0.pdf
```

You may need to play with variations of the `-r1200` parameter (higher or lower) for best results.

Comment: Thanks Kurt. Creating .tif image from Ghostscript seems a lot faster than convert. Is there a way to define the geometry of the image as we do in convert ?

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle Is it possible to do execute this gs command from inside a Python code?

Answer (score 1):

Since a comment asked *"How to define the geometry of an image when using Ghostscript as we do in `convert`?"*, here is an answer:

1. It does not make sense to define *geometry* (that is image dimensions) and *resolution* for a raster image created by Ghostscript at the same time.
2. Once you convert a *vector* based page of a given dimension (such as PDF) into a *raster* image (such as the TIFF G4 format) giving a desired resolution (as done in the other answer), you already indirectly and implicitly also did set the dimension:

   - The original PDF dimension of your sample file *sample_rotate-0.pdf* is `1008x612` points.
   - At a resolution of 72 DPI (the default Ghostscript uses if not given directly, or `-r72` in the Ghostscript command if given directly) the image dimensions will be `1008x612` pixels.
   - At a resolution of 720 DPI (`-r720` in the Ghostscript command) the image dimensions will be `10080x6120` pixels.
   - At a resolution of 1440 DPI (`-r1440` in the Ghostscript command of my other answer) the image dimensions will be `20160x12240` pixels.
   - At a resolution of 1200 DPI (`-r1200` in the Ghostscript command) the image dimensions will be `16800x10200` pixels.
   - At resolution of 1000 DPI (`-r1000` in the Ghostscript command) the image dimensions will be `14000x8500` pixels.
   - At a resolution of 120 DPI (`-r120` in the Ghostscript command) the image dimensions will be `1680x1020` pixels.
   - At resolution of 100 DPI (`-r100` in the Ghostscript command) the image dimensions will be `1400x850` pixels.
3. If you absolutely insist to specify the dimension/geometry for the output image on the Ghostscript commandline (rather than the resolution), you can do so by adding `-gNNNNxMMMM -dPDFFitPage` to the commandline.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kurt. You explained it really well. Thanks for taking your time to exlain this.

Answer (score 0):

There you can find decoded content of your file: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1YEM-11PerqSHpnb1RQcnJ4cFk

A absolutely sure the OCR is the best way to read pdf file, but you can try REGEX-ing the native content. It going to be be the hard and long way.

Comment: Hi Kurt! Nice to hear you! I just want to say: "Brutal force with the pdf source is pain and OSR - the bert way anyway". Thank you!

Comment: Sorry! OCR! English is not my first language. Thank you for correction!

Comment: What is that decoded pdf file ? How did you created the decoded file ? I dont see the tabular data in it.

Comment: How I mentioned before, the PDF have no "tabular data" or some kind "structured data" at all. The pdf file is a kind of graphical "vectorising" of the source. In your case, each word or digit (even part of word) is represented by coordinates and text content (word, part of word or digit). For example, the second line of the content decoded source says: bla bla bla, x:313.48, y:566.7204 text:"ANNUAL STATEMENT FOR THE YEAR 2011 OF THE  Minnesota Life Insurance Company". The data meaning pattern there is: BT [.+] (x) (y) Tm [(part of the text)[.+](part of the text)...] TJ ET

Comment: Unfortunate, I am using my own software for extracting, decoding and analyzing the parts of pdf file. I do not distribute it, but I am sure Kurt can help you with instructions to "Ghostscript" or some kind software to inflate internal parts of the file. Hi knows a lot about 3th part software.